# how to ignore chromedriver errors from showing up in log (selenium)

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, console

I'm using selenium for a scraping script along with a chromedriver service on windows here is how initialised them

```py
# Setting up the options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors=yes')

# Setting up service

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install(), log_output='nul')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)

# Rest of the code ...
```

My script is working fine I just want to ignore these annoying errors/warnings that keep showing up in the console anytime I run it,

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57253/devtools/browser/10819d8d-19ce-4893-8632-7c841dc8f6f7
[12856:28660:0307/001815.740:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
ERROR: Time is after notAfter
[12856:28660:0307/001818.072:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do that...

I tried adding this argument to the Service constructor but it did not fix it : `log_output='nul'`

I tried this also but it did not work:

```py
# Suppressing stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Setting up the options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# Instantiate the WebDriver with suppressed console errors

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__

# Rest of the code
```

Comment: @GillesQuénot I get the following error :
[12856:28660:0307/001815.740:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line:

```
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
```

```
0: verbose
1: info
2: warning
3: error
```